# How to receive digital audio via polling the SAI?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, embedded, digital-audio

I'm trying to receive digital audio on an STM32 by polling the SAI, via `HAL_SAI_Receive`.  Eventually I will switch to DMA; my goal now, though, is to simply be able to receive audio.

My code looks like:

```
for (;;) {
    sai_status = HAL_SAI_Receive(&hsai_BlockA4, buf, 8, 1000);
    ...
```

However, when I run it, I get `SAI SR` is 0 - there is never any data:

```
// From the STM32 HAL:
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_SAI_Receive(SAI_HandleTypeDef *hsai, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout)
{
// ... runs fine to this point
    /* Receive data */
    while (hsai->XferCount > 0U)
    {
      if ((hsai->Instance->SR & SAI_xSR_FLVL) != SAI_FIFOSTATUS_EMPTY)
// At this point, SR is always empty, no matter how long I wait
// (gdb) p *hsai->Instance
// $13 = {CR1 = 0xb10081, CR2 = 0x0, FRCR = 0x11f3f, SLOTR = 0xffff0300, IMR = 0x0, SR = 0x0, CLRFR = 0x0, DR = 0x0}
```

This is surprising, because I've already initialized the SAI, using the code autogenerated by STM32CubeMX:

```
 /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_SAI4_Init();
```

and confirmed via gdb that the code is running.  That code, among other things, calls `HAL_SAI_MspInit()` which calls  `__HAL_RCC_SAI4_CLK_ENABLE()`, so RCC should be enabled, and SAI configured.

What else do I need to do to get the SAI to start receiving data?

---

## Update

My investigation suggests that the issue is: The SAI needs a clock input, not only its own RCC, but a clock it uses for the audio, and the the code above does *not* configure this.

However: I'm not sure, and can find no reference on, how to configure such a clock input.